# Media query in responsive email template

Tags: css, email, media-queries, html-email, email-templates

I need to build a responsive email template. I did my research and learnt that media queries are not widely supported by the email clients.

So, I tried not to use media query and stacked the columns using `display: inline-block; max-width:290px;`.

1. But what if I want to change the font size for mobile version? Also I have a case where client wants few blocks to be visible in mobile but not on desktop. How can I achieve these without media query?
2. Also, in my case when I add style rules and media queries, I guess iOS supports media queries. But rues under media queries are not appearing but the other rules defines in `<style></style>` works just fine.

The template looks somewhat like this:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<style type="text/css">
   table {
       font-size: 24px;
   }
   #tdtoshowinmobile {
       display: none;
   }
   @media only screen and max-device-width(767px){
       table {
           font-size: 32px !important;
       }
       #tdtoshowinmobile {
           display: block !important;
       }
   }
</style>
</head>

<body>


    <table>
        ...tr...td....
    </table>
</body>
```

The above template adds the normal rules to inline elements but removes the media queries in my case. I read an article that says that mail clients remove style tags and add it to inline elements. And I guess since media queries can't be defined inline they are being ignored.

So, again my questions are:

1. how to change `font-size` or `color` etc in responsive email template without using media queries?
2. how to add media queries the right way?(For me adding them in `style` tag is not working)

Comment: CSS for email should all be inline `<table style="font-size: 12px">` only your media queries should remain in your `<style>` tags with `!important` after each style. You need to force the email client to respect the media query.

Comment: I have important after all the rules in media queries. And as you said I now moved all the rules to inline while keeping only media query inside `style` tag. but media queries are not being applied.

Comment: In the year 2016, email layout is still a pain in the ass. Oh my God, this seems to not change anymore!

Comment: Have you included the viewport meta to your `<head>`?  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: yes you can see my question. I updated it a few minutes ago to show how I have included it

Comment: the !important in media query is very important here. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1 Think it can be done only using media query. 
Some popular mobile mail clients support media query, so in my opinion it's worth.

2 Hope this code can help you

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px),
screen and (max-width: 767px)     {

}
```

also, maybe use some [doctype](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/correct-doctype-to-use-in-html-email/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If you lookin for responsive email example with multiple columns please take a look at [litmus](https://litmus.com/resources/free-responsive-email-templates) or other free templates ( [this](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/archived-versions/version%201/template-default.html) one looks really good as example )